# wxPython ListCtrl : write Colored text

Tags: python, wxpython

Trying to write string to a ListCtrl , I don't understand the logic completely. Is this the proper way?

```
    self.rightPanel = wx.ListCtrl(spliter, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
    self.rightPanel.InsertColumn(0, 'LineNumber')
    self.rightPanel.InsertColumn(1, 'log')
    self.rightPanel.SetColumnWidth(0, 8)
    self.rightPanel.SetColumnWidth(1, 80)

def writeConsole(self,str):
    item = wx.ListItem()
    item.SetText(str)
    item.SetTextColour(wx.RED)
    item.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLACK)                    
    index = self.rightPanel.GetItemCount()        
    self.rightPanel.InsertItem(item)
    self.rightPanel.SetStringItem(index, 0, str(index))
    self.rightPanel.SetStringItem(index, 1, item.GetText())
```

1-Why text is not displayed in color ?
2-Why there are 2 different methods for display text in ListCtrl?

```
   ListCtrl.InsertItem()
   ListCtrl.SetStringItem()
```

I think InsertItem just loads the item to list.SetString but displays the item content.(Not Sure)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SetTextColour()` and `SetBackgroundColour()` are methods of the entire listctrl, not of items.
For items you should use (valid only for report mode):

```
GetItemTextColour(idx_item)
SetItemTextColour(idx_item, col)
```

`InsertItem(index, item)` (item here is an instance of `wx.ListItem`) is one of the `InsertItem()` methods to add a new row on a ListCtrl.

`SetStringItem(index, col, label, imageId=-1)` (where index and col parameters are the row and column indexes for a cell) allows setting strings in any selected column. Other insert methods work only for the first column.

**Reference:** *wxPython in Action*, Noel Rappin and Robin Dunn.